# Django: Login a user after clicking on the activation link from email

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, email-validation, activation

I have tried to login a user after the user clicks the activation link send to the user's email. But directly using the `login()` method will throw me the error `'User' object has no attribute 'backend'`. I have tried using `authenticate()` method but since i need to use the password already stored in the backend, `authenticate(username, password)` does not return any user.

Here is my activation view

```
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

To solve the issue of `User object has no attribute backend` I used authenticate as:

```
username = user.username
password = user.password
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    login(request, user)
```

No user is returned. Can somenone help me?

Edit:
I am using Django 1.8.11 and python2.7

```
Traceback:
File "/home/sanip/naxa/source/fieldsight/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/sanip/naxa/source/fieldsight/onadata/apps/users/views.py" in activate
  628.         login(request, user)
File "/home/sanip/naxa/source/fieldsight/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in login
  112.     request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] = user.backend

Exception Type: AttributeError at /users/activate/NjYx/53u-911ceda96c18c2e7dce1/

Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

Comment: post your User Model and the full traceback

Comment: I have used the default django User model

Comment: if you are using so, what are you getting when you are decoding the uid64?? i dont think it will give you the ID from that,

Comment: Have you saved the user in signup view? Can you add signup view, not all, just after `if form.is_valid` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need to provide the stock backend here directly as a variable

Try Again With This:

```
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'   #<-- addition
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

Comment: Adding the backend directly solved my issue. Thanks a lot @ans2human

Comment: Welcome @Sanip, thanks for accepting the answer, show further support by upvoting too.

Comment: i would love to upvote the answer but i lack reputations.

Comment: Thanks a lot and will upvote the answer soon after I am able to.